# category of linear maps between fixed vector spaces

Tags: category-theory

Let $V,W$ be fixed $k$-vector spaces. Let $C$ be the category whose objects are linear map $f:V\to W$ and morphisms from $f$ to $g$ are pair of linear maps $(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha:V\to V,\beta :W\to W$ such that $g \circ\alpha = \beta \circ f$.

I want to find the product in this category. Note that $C$ is the full subcategory of $D$, whose objects are linear maps between any $k$-vector spaces, with morphisms $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that $g \circ\alpha = \beta \circ f$. I proved that in $D$, the product of linear maps $f_i:V_i \to W_i$, $ i \in I$ is given by $f: \prod_{i\in I} V_i \to \prod_{i\in I} W_i$ where $f((v_i))=(f_i(v_i))$.

So given $f_i:V \to W$ in $C$, if there exists isomorphisms $\prod V\simeq V$ and $\prod W\simeq W$, we can also find the product in $C$.

But is it the necessary condition? In other words, if there exists product of $f_i:V\to W$ in $C$, then is it true that $\prod V\simeq V$ and $\prod W\simeq W$?